# Flutter put AnimatedIcon instead of AppBar leading icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

in my application i'm trying to using `AnimatedIcon` instead of `Appbar`, `leading` icon, for changing controller of `AnimatedIcon` i'm using `Provider` package, but i get this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

my `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
  elevation: 8.0,
  titleSpacing: 0.0,
  automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
  leading: Consumer<AppBarAnimatedIconMode>(
      builder: (context, mode, child) => ValueListenableProvider.value(
          value: mode.iconMode,
          child: Consumer<bool>(
              builder: (context, value, child) => AppBarAnimatedIcon(
                    animate: value,
                  )))),
```

`AppBarAnimatedIcon` class:

```
class AppBarAnimatedIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool animate;

  const AppBarAnimatedIcon({@required this.animate});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AppBarAnimatedIcon();
}

class _AppBarAnimatedIcon extends State<AppBarAnimatedIcon> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  bool get _animate => widget.animate;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    if(_animate){
      _animationController.forward();
    }else{
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
        progress: _animationController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`ValueNotifier` class to change `AnimatedIcon` animation controller:

```
class AppBarAnimatedIconMode {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> iconMode = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  // ignore: use_setters_to_change_properties
  void changeIconMode() {
    iconMode.value = !iconMode.value;
  }
}
```

full error message:

```
This _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<bool> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<bool>
  value: false
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: BuildDefaultAppBar
  dirty
  dependencies: [_EffectiveTickerMode]
  state: _BuildDefaultAppBar#a5ab5(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4167:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:6)
#2      _InheritedProviderScopeMixin.markNeedsNotifyDependents (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:269:5)
#3      _DeferredDelegateState.setState (package:provider/src/deferred_inherited_provider.dart:139:17)
#4      ValueListenableProvider._startListening.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:provider/src/value_listenable_provider.dart:74:38)
...
The ValueNotifier<bool> sending notification was: ValueNotifier<bool>#7aa18(true)
```

Comment: Use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` instead, it's more efficient for your case.

Comment: @mFeinstein i get error again

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem is for the code you posted, but I think it's related to how you are using the Provider package, you are using it too much, can't you simplify things?

Comment: @mFeinstein i think yes, i can, are you familiar with `Provider`?

Comment: I am, I would start by checking that changeIconMode(), specially as you are ignoring a warning

Comment: @mFeinstein let me reproduce simple application

Comment: @mFeinstein i found out problem and i fixed, problem was calling more again to change icon mode in widget tree

Comment: I tried reproducing your error but goto no errors. This exception is thrown when Flutter was building the widget tree and something got changed. Anything can be changed once the widget tree has been build(laid out) or before not in the meantime. Your value is getting changed when the widget tree is building.

Comment: @NadeemSiddique  i found out problem and i fixed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and I tried your code. Firstly if you use Provider, you should use **ChangeNotifier** with your control classes. Also you should use **ChangeNotifierProvider** with your main class. These are my codes which is working well.

> main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => AppBarAnimatedIconMode(), // This is condition class.
        child: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> AppBarAnimatedIconMode.dart

```
class AppBarAnimatedIconMode with ChangeNotifier {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> iconMode = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  // ignore: use_setters_to_change_properties
  void changeIconMode() {
    iconMode.value = !iconMode.value;
    notifyListeners(); // For change the state of icon value.
  }
}
```

> AppBarAnimatedIcon.dart

```
class AppBarAnimatedIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool animate;

  const AppBarAnimatedIcon({@required this.animate});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AppBarAnimatedIcon();
}

class _AppBarAnimatedIcon extends State<AppBarAnimatedIcon> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {// You should use SingleTickerProviderStateMixin //
  AnimationController _animationController;

  bool get _animate => widget.animate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() { // Also dispose your animation when you dispose the class.
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_animate) { // You should check your conditions in your build() for animate
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
        progress: _animationController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So you can control you animation like this function:

```
RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Change'),
      onPressed: () {
        var provider = Provider.of<AppBarAnimatedIconMode>(context, listen: false);
        provider.changeIconMode();
      },
```

---

Also on your AppBar, you can use this code. Yours is complicated.

```
AppBar(
    title: Text('Deneme'),
    leading: Consumer<AppBarAnimatedIconMode>(
      builder: (context, mode, child) => AppBarAnimatedIcon(
        animate: mode.iconMode,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

And for AppBarAnimatedIconMode.dart

```
class AppBarAnimatedIconMode with ChangeNotifier {
  bool iconMode = false;

  void changeIconMode() {
    iconMode = !iconMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```